# ballroom dancers proplem using semaphore

Tags: java, semaphore

I am trying to write a solution for 'Exclusive Queue' problem from 'Little book of Semaphores'. Problem is stated as follows:

Imagine that threads represent ballroom dancers and that two kinds of dancers, leaders and followers, wait in two queues before entering the dance floor. When a leader arrives, it checks to see if there is follower waiting. If so, they can both proceeds. Otherwise it waits.

Similarly, when a follower arrives, it checks for a leader and either proceeds or waits, accordingly.

I put the following ballroom class:

```
public class Ballroom {

public void leaderEntered(){
//the calling leader thread will either block, waiting for
//follower or will proceed to dance
dance();
}

public void followerEntered(){
//the calling followerthread will either block, waiting for
//leader or will proceed to dance
dance();
}

private void dance(){
System.out.println("doing dance");
}

}
```

and here is the  code for learder

```
mutex.wait()
if followers > 0:
    followers--
    followerQueue.signal()
else:
leaders++
mutex.signal()
leaderQueue.wait()
dance()
rendezvous.wait()
mutex.signal()
```

and here is the code for followers

```
mutex.wait()
if leaders> 0:
   leaders--
   leadersQueue.signal()
else:
followers++
mutex.signal()
followersQueue.wait()
dance()
rendezvous.wait()
```

how I continue??

Answer (score 0):

This sounds very similar to the sleeping barber problem. Try looking at this:
[Sleeping Barber algorithm (with multiple barbers)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19692515/sleeping-barber-algorithm-with-multiple-barbers)

You can read more about the problem here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleeping_barber_problem

Comment: thank you..but this isn't similar..because in Sleeping Barber problem there are one berber .. in my problem there are many leaders.

Comment: No problem but the link I provided actually has a "multiple barber" solution.